# setting state in React JS

Tags: reactjs

my component state looks like this:

```
  this.state = { 
        user: {firstname: '', lastName: '', phoneNumber: '' }
     }
```

on an input change event, I want to set state.  But the below code does not seem to be working.  What am I stupidly doing wrong?

```
 handlePhoneNumberChange(e){
     this.setState({["users"]['phoneNumber']: e.target.value});
  }
```

Comment: `{["users"]['phoneNumber']: e.target.value}` is not valid JavaScript (this has nothing to do with React).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update the state like this instead:

```
handlePhoneNumberChange(e) {
   let user = this.state.user;
   user.phoneNumber = e.target.value;
   this.setState(user);
}
```

You may also want to look into [ES6 spread properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), which cleans this process up significantly.

Edit: Changed "spread operator" to "spread properties", thanks Felix.

Comment: You might want pass a function to setState, because .setState is async. In this simple case there probably won't be a problem. But it's considered as a good pratice to pass function instead like this : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508). If you are referring to spread **properties**, then you should say that.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh, my bad, thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're doing, but if you want to set the phone number of the current user:

```
this.setState({ user: { ...this.state.user, phoneNumber: e.target.value } })
```

assuming you have access to experimental ES features like spread.

Otherwise,

```
this.setState({ user: Object.assign({}, this.state.user, {phoneNumber: e.target.value}) })
```

Comment: What you are suggesting, spread properties, is actually an *experimental* feature. It's not part of any version of ES yet.

Comment: ah, my bad, babel makes it easy to forget